# AS3 "navigateToURL" freezes after 4 "gotoAndStop()" functions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am developing an small `.swf` that is embedded in a SharePoint page, everything work perfectly except my `navigateToURL` script. This `.swf` have some buttons to navigate between frames and one `navigateToURL` button per frame. Every frame have some info about the page to navigate and so I am  guessing some people would read every page before making a decision, and here is where the problem begins. But let me show you my script:

```
trainingSUB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, irtrainingsub1);
function irtrainingsub1(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(2);
}

templatesSUB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, irtemplatessub1);
function irtemplatessub1(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(3);
}

servicesSUB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, irservicessub1);
function irservicessub1(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(4);
}

communitySUB.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ircommunitysub1);
function ircommunitysub1(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(5);
}

visitBTN.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, abrirweb1);
function abrirweb1(event:MouseEvent):void {
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("https://example.com"), "_self");
}
```

The problem I have found is that after you navigate the 4 frames and return to some of the pages, the `navigateToURL` button will take you to the fourth page you visited.

Example, click #1-templates, #2-community, #3-services, #4-training, #5-community, at this point if I click the navigate button it will take me to "training" and not to the "community" page, and no matter how many more frames I go to, it always send me to the fourth page I visited.

Any suggestion?

Comment: naming conflict probably.

Comment: How does this script generate different urls to visit?What happens if you only click 3 buttons, then the visit button?

Comment: every frame you visit is related with the other with a similar script and his own URL to go. if you hit the button 3 times, it acts normally, just as its supposed to, the problem is when you move between frames more than 4 times. then the visit button frozen with the URL of the fourth frame you were.